# Google Maps API v2 - Only white map tiles on my display

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I've a problem with Google Maps: no map appears, only white map tiles like this: http://oi47.tinypic.com/2uh0sk0.jpg

I've tried to generete a new API key, but it still doesn't work, I can't understand why...

Here the logcat:

```
04-02 11:04:07.459: W/dalvikvm(32502): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3693: Lcom/fullwipe/bolognacityguide/Mapexample;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
04-02 11:04:07.499: W/dalvikvm(32502): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 23
04-02 11:04:07.859: W/dalvikvm(32502): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/s; (425)
04-02 11:04:07.859: W/dalvikvm(32502): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/s;' failed
04-02 11:04:07.859: W/dalvikvm(32502): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/y/bo; (3818)
04-02 11:04:07.859: W/dalvikvm(32502): Link of class 'Lmaps/y/bo;' failed
04-02 11:04:07.859: W/dalvikvm(32502): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/i/k; (4206)
04-02 11:04:07.859: W/dalvikvm(32502): Link of class 'Lmaps/i/k;' failed
04-02 11:04:07.859: E/dalvikvm(32502): Could not find class 'maps.i.k', referenced from method maps.z.ag.a
04-02 11:04:07.859: W/dalvikvm(32502): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3538 (Lmaps/i/k;) in Lmaps/z/ag;
04-02 11:04:09.449: E/Adreno200-ES20(32502): **** 32547: glUseProgram(0)
04-02 11:04:10.109: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2ca458, bufid: 0
04-02 11:04:10.109: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
04-02 11:04:10.119: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2ca458, bufid: 1
04-02 11:04:10.119: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
04-02 11:04:11.869: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2ca458, bufid: 0
04-02 11:04:11.949: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
04-02 11:04:11.979: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2ca458, bufid: 1
04-02 11:04:11.999: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
04-02 11:04:12.069: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2ca458, bufid: 0
04-02 11:04:12.089: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
04-02 11:04:12.199: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2ca458, bufid: 1
04-02 11:04:12.199: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
04-02 11:04:12.239: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2ca458, bufid: 0
04-02 11:04:12.249: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
04-02 11:04:12.279: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Enter: GetBackBuffer(), surface: 0x2ca458, bufid: 1
04-02 11:04:12.299: E/Adreno200-EGLSUB(32502): Return: GetBackBuffer(), TRUE
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
                android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
                android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
                android:required="false" />

  <permission android:name="com.kurtis.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.kurtis.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icona"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.kurtis.myapp.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.kurtis.myapp.Mapexample"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXq9M" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity:

```
package com.kurtis.myapp;

import com.example.android.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Mapexample extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapexample);

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                // The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Have you got any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: you have Creating an API Project https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr-FR ???

Comment: chec kmy ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15761977/1168654

Comment: @kurtis92 did you solve your problem? if not, could you please update your question by editing it and let us know so far what have you done?

Answer (score 2):

you have problem in package name in android manifes file:

check this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

and

```
<permission android:name="com.kurtis.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.kurtis.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

correct it to same.

You have added diffrent permission for `MAPS_RECEIVE` then how it recive maps?? change it to

```
<permission android:name="com.example.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="com.example.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: you want simple google map v2 demo?? then use it from android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services import google_play_services all project from that folder. you get com.example.mapdemo sample code just add MAP API KEY and check that is working if yes then compare taht code with your.

Answer (score 0):

when you generate API key, ensure that you are doing so for DEBUG mode too.
i guess, thats the root cause of your problem.

you will need two separate keys; one for DEV (unsigned app to use in emulator etc)
and one for LIVE (to use when signing your app).

Answer (score 0):

1. your package name in Manifest should be `:com.kurtis.myapp` not `com.example.android`
2. Try using `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` in your layout
3. In your Main Activity use Activity not FragmentActivity and replace 
   `mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
       mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);`

   with this:

   `mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
               .getMap();
   mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);`

Hope this helpfull

Comment: Point 1 will help but point 2 and 3 won't help, rather it will confuse the person asking the question.
SupportMapFragment isn't really the problem. SupportMapFragment is used whenever you are willing to let you app useful for SDK's below 12.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google API  console, make sure that you've got the "Google Maps Android API v2" service turned on, and not just the "Google Maps API v2" service.